# unable to resolve class issue with Executing Grrovy Scripts in Java in Wildfly with Camel CDI

Tags: java, groovy, apache-camel, cdi, wildfly-10

**Background :**

I'm invoking a Groovy script using GrrovyShell as this.

```
@GET
@Path("/endpoint/{param}")
public Response getEndpointService(@PathParam("param") String messageId) {

    String scriptPath = "/path/to/Grrovyfile.gsh";

    Binding binding = new Binding();
    binding.setProperty("in", inParams);

    GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);
    shell.evaluate(new File(scriptPath));

}
```

**Groovy Script File :**

```
def condition = "good"
def severity = "N/A"
def detail = ""

import net.sf.json.JSONObject
import java.util.Random

try{

    def detailMap = [
        condition: condition,
        success: false,
        severity: severity,
    ]

    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(detailMap)
    detail = jsonObject.toString()
}
```

And there is a seperate camel router implementation in this war and it is get initialized with camel cdi.

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.cdi.ContextName;

@ApplicationScoped
@ContextName("camel-cdi-context")
public class MiscRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
      // router dsl
    }

}
```

**Problem :** 

Above groovy code is getting failed with below error when the router is stared with the camel cdi. But is succeeded with no errors when the `@ApplicationScoped`, `@ContextName("camel-cdi-context")` lines are commented.

```
12:47:28,108 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11) org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
12:47:28,109 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11) /path/to/Grrovyfile.gsh: 9: unable to resolve class net.sf.json.JSONObject
12:47:28,109 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11)  @ line 9, column 1.
12:47:28,109 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11)    import net.sf.json.JSONObject
12:47:28,109 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11)    ^
12:47:28,109 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11) 
12:47:28,109 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11) 1 error
12:47:28,109 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11) 
12:47:28,110 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11)   at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
12:47:28,110 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11)   at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:958)
12:47:28,110 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11)   at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
12:47:28,113 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11)   at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:554)
12:47:28,113 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11)   at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
12:47:28,113 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11)   at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
12:47:28,113 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11)   at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
12:47:28,113 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11)   at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
12:47:28,113 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11)   at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:584)
12:47:28,114 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11)   at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:632)
12:47:28,114 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11)   at TestGroovy.getEndpointService(TestGroovy.java:91)
12:47:28,114 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11)   at org.jboss.weld.proxies.TestGroovy$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getEndpointService(Unknown Source)
```

I assume this is an class loading issue and I'm trying to resolve this. Expect a little help here.

**Already tried :**

- Provided these dependant jars as modules using jboss-deployment-structure.xml.
- Provided imports to `GroovyShell` using `ImportCustomizer` in `CompilerConfiguration`
- Tried to load this using a Startup Singleton EJB also.
- Tried to load this using a seperate injection
- Tried to load the JSONObject in seperate static class

**Note :**

- Please note that the relevant jars are already in the war file (WEB-INF/lib).
- This same issue happens for other third party artifacts like  `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode`,  `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` also.
- But this issue doesn't happen for third party artifacts like `org.apache.log4j.Logger`. (may be they are already loaded through wildfly)

**Update :**

I'm one step closer to the answer.As per the [forums / artiles](https://dzone.com/articles/class-loading-fun-groovy) classLoader returns all classes on the CLASSPATH when the JVM started. 
So, I tried adding the related artifacts manually and invoke the script using the classloaders rather than GroovyShell. And it worked! Now need to find a way to load these classes in these artifacts at the JVM start / add them to the class path within wildfly.

```
URL[] classLoaderUrls = new URL[] {
        new URL("file:///path/to/repo/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar"),
        new URL("file:///path/to/repo/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar"),
        new URL("file:///path/to/repo/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar"),
        new URL("file:///path/to/repo/commons-lang-2.5.jar"),
        new URL("file:///path/to/repo/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"),
        new URL("file:///path/to/repo/groovy-all-2.4.11.jar"),
        new URL("file:///path/to/repo/net/sf/json/main/ezmorph-1.0.6.jar") };

URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(classLoaderUrls);

//GroovyClassLoader groovyClassLoader = new GroovyClassLoader(urlClassLoader);
GroovyClassLoader groovyClassLoader = new GroovyClassLoader();

Script script = InvokerHelper.createScript(groovyClassLoader.parseClass(new
        File(scripts)), binding);
System.out.println("getEndpointService().script : " + script);

Object responseObj = script.run();
```

**Versions :**

- Wildfly version : 10.1.0
- Wildfly Camle Patch : 4.9.0
- Groovy version : groovy-all-2.4.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by my self.

This issue can be resolved when you are using GroovyClassLoader instead of GroovyShell. Actually I dig into the GroovyShell by decompiling it and I saw this is used in there also. 

Note :  if the jars in the classpath you don't need to import them manually using URLClassLoader as mentoned in the above post.

So with the below implementation it works fine now.

```
GroovyClassLoader groovyClassLoader = new GroovyClassLoader();

Script script = InvokerHelper.createScript(groovyClassLoader.parseClass(new
        File(scriptPath)), binding);
logger.info("getEndpointService().script : " + script);

Object responseObj = script.run();

logger.info("getEndpointService().responseObj : " + responseObj);
```

Further you can use GroovyCodeSource also if you need to play with codeBase like additional attributes.

```
GroovyCodeSource groovyCodeSource = new GroovyCodeSource(new File(scriptPath));

GroovyClassLoader groovyClassLoader = new GroovyClassLoader();

Script script = InvokerHelper.createScript(groovyClassLoader.parseClass(groovyCodeSource), binding);
logger.info("getEndpointService().script : " + script);

Object responseObj = script.run();

logger.info("getEndpointService().responseObj : " + responseObj);
```

Comment: You don't need to decompile anything Groovy, the sources are fully available..!